# Writing RoboVM bindings

Tags: java, binding, libgdx, robovm

While finally trying to bind some obj-c libraries  (admob) I ran into my first problem:

Since the only documentation I could find on binding anything was in one of libgdx forum thread it didn't mentioned how to bind constants like:

```
extern GADAdSize const kGADAdSizeBanner;
```

How should those be bind to java?

Heres the GADAdSize.h file from google: http://pastebin.com/f5UjCszj

And heres my silly attempt at trying to get one of the constants bind to java: http://pastebin.com/kV8BMvwh

EDIT: After some research i found out that @GlobalValue should be used somehow for this. Can anyone construct a simple sample?

Thank you very much!